# How many Troop Transports do I need to take a minor race planet in BOTF?

Tags: star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

How many Troop Transports do I need to take a minor race planet in BOTF?  Is their some ratio of troop transports to ground combat rating that I should follow?

Note that I'm already taking out all the Orbital Batteries and Shields before I invade, but my troops are always wiped out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the difference between your tech and their tech, coupled with various bonuses from your respective "empires"...And if the race has a built-in ground combat bonus (which a lot of the minor races do) then that applies as well.

[Here is a thread that goes into more detail than you'll ever want.](http://www.armadafleetcommand.com/onscreen/botf/viewtopic.php?f=156&t=1632)

Comment: +1 for link, you need to be sure to bombard the dirty aliens a fair bit (at least a turn or two) before landing your transports, after you've gotten rid of shields & orbital batteries.

Comment: @tzhx: I almost always just make them love me. They're inordinately hard to invade.

Comment: Dead link.  Anyone have teh new one @TZHX.

Comment: @C.Ross ok. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The rough ratio is: 2 Transporter / 100 ground forces

Things that increase your transporter strength though:

1. Experience, for example: Legendary > Veteran
2. Ship level (given ratio is for shiplevel 2)
3. Your race, some transporters are slightly better
4. Last but not least some luck :)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  Please take a look at the [About].  Thanks for the answer :-).